# Getting incorrect value after Split

Tags: c#

I want to send a message to some user with an ID stored in `string[] words`. I have tried to output it to `lable_name.Text`. ID displays correct, but it looks like `string user_id` in the next method doesn't see it correct.
I have tried to change `lable_name.Text = words[2]` for `lable_name.Text = "65896237"` and all was good.

I just looked into Debuger - and it says, that `lable_name.Text="65896237\r\n"`
is it the reason? and how can I get clear value?

```
  private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = listBox1.Items.Count -1;
            for (int counter = count; counter >= 0; counter--)
            {
                if (listBox1.GetSelected(counter))
                { 
                     string[] words= listBox1.Items[counter].ToString().Split(' ');
                     lable_name.Text = words[2];
                }
            }
        }

        private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioMessage.Checked==true)
            {
            string user_id = lable_name.Text;
            string message = textBox1.Text;
            string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id="+user_id+"&message="+message+"&v=5.31&access_token=...";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            RootObject response = (RootObject)json_serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(RootObject));
            MessageBox.Show("This is Message");
            }
            else
            {...
```

Comment: The simplest solution might be a simple `lable_name.Text = words[2].trim()`, but you might want to look into where you are getting that newline from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just looked into Debuger - and it says, that lable_name.Text="65896237\r\n" is it the reason? and how can I get clear value?

You can [trim white space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as space, tab, carriage return and newline from a variable like

```
string trimmed = lable_name.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the `/n` and `/r` before or after the split

```
int count = listBox1.Items.Count -1;
for (int counter = count; counter >= 0; counter--)
{
    if (listBox1.GetSelected(counter))
    { 
        string[] words= listBox1.Items[counter].ToString().Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Split(' ');
        lable_name.Text = words[2];
    }
}
```